# Eclipse plugin: Dialog for shared object

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I am trying to write an eclipse plugin where I have two views sharing a global object state. The object state gets looked up when each of the views get loaded. If the object is in some default state (say at startup of the plugin), I display a Dialog to prompt for a value for this object.

As a result when both views load as part of the perspective, the dialog appears twice due to concurrency. So the problem is, if the first thread has opened the dialog, the second thread needs to wait till the dialog has captuired the response and closed.

But I noticed that invoking `dialog.open` (with block set to `true`) actually lets the second thread in, and hence shows the dialog for a second time.

Any hints about how I can make the second thread wait?

Comment: The block in `dialog.open` only blocks the UI thread. If you are using other threads you will need to use one of the many Java synchronization classes and primitives to synchronize the threads.

Comment: @greg-449 Thanks for your response! You are right - what I was doing as a workaround was to load my views synchronously. I was trying to see if it can be handled asynchronously, but I guess it eventually will land me up in the same situation. At least here, I would be going through the standard Eclipse concurrency framework.